# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' within dictionary

Tags: python

Implement the function consolidate, which accepts zero or more sequences in the star parameter `seqs`, and returns a dictionary whose keys consist of values found in those sequences, which in turn map to numbers indicating how many times each value appears across all the sequences.

E.g. `consolidate([1,2,3], [1,1,1], [2,4], [1])` should return the dictionary `{1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}`.

My code:

```py
def consolidate(*seqs):
    d={}
    for i in seqs:              
        for number in seqs:   
            d[number]=d.get(number,0)+1   

    return d

print(consolidate([1,2,3], [1,1,1], [2,4], [1]))
```

The error: `TypeError: unhashable type`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, should be `for number in i` not `for number in seqs`. You're currently trying to use a list as a dictionary key.

```py
def consolidate(*seqs):
  d = {}
  for i in seqs:
    for number in i:
      d[number] = d.get(number,0) + 1
  return d
```

---

It would probably be better to call `i` somthing like `seq` => `for seq in seqs`.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a subclass of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that was made for use cases just like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def consolidate(*seq):
    return dict(Counter([x for l in seq for x in l]))

print(consolidate([1,2,3], [1,1,1], [2,4], [1]))
```

**Output:**

```
{1: 5, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def consolidate(*seqs):

  d={} 
  for i in seqs:
    for number in i: # here is the problem, should be i not seqs
      d[number]=d.get(number,0)+1
  return d  

print(consolidate([1,2,3], [1,1,1], [2,4], [1]))
```

P.S. Try to print the intermediate result when you debugging.  It is very useful for tracing the problem.